# Dreamweaver PHP mySQL insert to WordPress wpdb Conversion

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, insert, dreamweaver

I would like to know how to convert this Dreamweaver generated code to what I need to use for mySQL forms in WordPress. If I use my code on a blank page (just the form and SQL) it works fine. When I post this into a template, it doesn't. I think I am using the wrong method inside of wordPress. I have seen and read the wpdb page but it lacks in depth details on hooking it to forms.

This code is mostly generated by Dreamweaver. I know it needs to be changed but not sure what to swap out. I included it all to be thorough.

```
<?php require_once('../../../Connections/LocalHost.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO fyxt_characters (wp_userid, public_char, char_rank) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['wp_userid'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['public_char'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['char_rank'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_LocalHost, $LocalHost);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $LocalHost) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
</form>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Wp_userid:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="wp_userid" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Public_char:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="public_char" value="1" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Char_rank:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="char_rank" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect
    **if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {
      $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO fyxt_characters (wp_userid, public_char, char_rank) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",**
is what really need to be changed but am not sure. This is my first insert form. I have done lots of SELECT type queries in WordPress but have not yet worked with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE stuff.

Thank you so much for your direction and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a bunch of research and some experimentation I have found the solution. Basically the auto generated code is not what you want to use, however you can use bits and pieces of it to build the custom code quickly. Such as building the form fields for you. Here is the new code for WordPress that does the same thing that the Dreamweaver code does. On top of that, the WordPress API wpdb sanitizes and does much of the other work you would otherwise have to do manually. Pretty cool if you ask me!

The form stays the same as I am just going to use what Dreamweaver builds because it is quick and easy. Delete everything else that Dreamweaver created and replace it with the code the code below using WordPress's $wpdb.

```
<?php 
<!-- initialize wpdb -->
global $wpdb;
<!-- grab wordpress information -->
get_currentuserinfo();
$AccountID = $current_user->ID 
?>

<!-- THIS IS MY CUSTOME WP DB API CODE -->
<?php
$tableName = 'TableName';
$editFormAction = $wpdb->insert (
                        $tableName,
                        Array(
                            'wp_userid' => $AccountID, 
                            'public_char' => $_POST['public_char'], 
                            'char_rank' => $_POST['char_rank']
                            )
                    ); 
<!-- comment this out when not debugging -->
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
?>
```

That's all there is to it. I used the editFormAction variable that Dreamweaver created and then rewrote all the code after it to use the wpdb method. This form still needs validation, tightening up of form fields etc but that is how I converted from Dreamweaver generated PHP SQL Insert to WordPress SQL Insert. It is nice, clean and concise code and does all the cleaning and sanitizing for you. I thought this was going to be more complicated. I love Wordpress!